# How to fix 'str' object is not a mapping error

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I will start saying its't a duplicated question. My problem is a little different in an url with Django 2.2.

An view triggers 'str' object is not a mapping error when return HttpResponseRedirect to another view in same application.

I really don't know what's wrong. I use same method in other application in same project and it works.

Project urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', Home.as_view()),
    path('dashboard/', include('dashboard.urls')),
    path('main/', include('main.urls'))
]
```

Application urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.Section.as_view(), name='main-form')
]
```

Application views.py

```py
class Home(View):
  def get(self, request):
    return render(request, 'index.html', context={})

  def post(self, request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main-form'))


class Section(View):

  def get(self, request):
    return HttpResponse("Test Ok")
```

After post home form it should redirect to main-form view (Section view class) but I get error.

It triggers same error if I use the url in a template url `{% url 'main-form' %}`

If I navigate manually to view from address bar, view renders fine.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 17):

You probably wrote a URL pattern like this:

```
path('register-sms/', GetPhoneNumberView.as_view(), 'register-sms'),
```

Instead of like this:

```
path('register-sms/', GetPhoneNumberView.as_view(), name='register-sms'),
```

`name` is a keyword argument, if you leave it out, that string becomes the value for `kwargs` and you get this error.  Simple fix if you know what to look for.

Answer (score 3):

**Try to include an app name for your django app urls.py file like**

```
app_name ='smth'

urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.Section.as_view(), name='main-form')
]
```

Then in your template view file include: `href={% url 'smth:main-form' %}`

Comment: Thank you very much @Okayjosh
I don't know why, but I remake the project and it works.